# Notepad++ bug or settngs?

Tags: settings, notepad++

Suppose I type `ABEF` then I want to add `CD` after `B` to get the wanted text: `ABCDEF`.

To get the result I want I have to type `CDEF` instead just typing `CD`.

Some more explanation. when want to add `CD` after `B` 
it should add space for the `CD` between `AB` and `EF`. 
However, in error it replaces the `EF` so I have to type `CDEF` instead `CD` only.

Is it setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ and many other programs support both "Insert" and "Overstrike" modes of editing. You are describing the behaviour of "Overstrike". The bottom right hand corner of the Notepad++ window should contain either "INS" or "OVR" to indicate the current mode. Pressing the "Insert" key on a normal keyboard toggles the mode. (On my keyboard the "Insert" key is in a block of six keys, the others are "Home", "End", "Delete", "Page up" and "Page down.)

Comment: Great @user3644914. If this answer was the solution then please consider accepting it as the answer so that others will know how to sole similar issues. If it is not the solution then please add an answer yourself that explains how the problem was solved.

Comment: sory, i'm new here. so i don't know such a feature. do you know how to make the post solved icon?